# CocoaAsyncSocket / GCDAsyncSocket add a delay between writes on the queue

Tags: queue, delay, cocoaasyncsocket, gcdasyncsocket

I have the following function:

```
if (socket==nil)
  socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
if (elBuffer==nil) 
  elBuffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

if ([socket isDisconnected]) {
  NSError *err = nil;
  [socket connectToHost:elControlador.ip onPort:9761 error:&err]
}

[socket writeData:@"A01" withTimeout:30 tag:1];
[socket writeData:@"A02" withTimeout:30 tag:1];
[socket writeData:@"A03" withTimeout:30 tag:1];
[socket writeData:@"A04" withTimeout:30 tag:1];
[socket writeData:@"A05" withTimeout:30 tag:1];
[socket readDataWithTimeout:30 buffer:elBuffer bufferOffset:0 maxLength:-1 tag:1];
```

It works prefectly, except for the fact that the socket server needs a second or so between writes  for it to work.  I was wondering if anyone has run into the same problem and could shed a light on how to achieve this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using the following:

```
int i=0;
for(id aItem in aIDs) {
  NSString *directCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A%@",aItem];
  [self performSelector:@selector(fSend:) withObject:directCommand afterDelay:(2.0*i)];
  i++;
}
[socket readDataWithTimeout:30 buffer:elBuffer bufferOffset:0 maxLength:-1 tag:1];

-(void)fSend : (NSString *)aCommand {
  [socket writeData:aCommand withTimeout:30 tag:1];
}
```

This gives me a 2 seconds between performing the writeData without having to freeze the app and without flooding my equipment with writes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the client to wait between writing these strings:

- Put them into an array.
- Use a repeating `NSTimer`
- In the timer callback, write one line at a time until the array is exhausted, then invalidate the timer.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to have an array and keep track of the index, but it did give me an idea how to fix it.  Thanks.